# Inability to deploy the WEB Api using Visual Studio

Tags: azure, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

I have created a web API, and now I want to deploy it. Unfortunately, when I try to publish my web API, I need to sign in or create a new account on the App Service step.[problematic step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fa0Un.png)

When I try to log in or even create a new account - it accepts it but doesn't allow me to go further and open the App Service settings like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEuG8.png)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I believe the user which is logged in your Visual Studio, is not the same with permissions on Azure. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/signing-in-to-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, it was because I didn't activate any subscription. But in my opinion, instead of just not allowing me to deploy my WEB API, they could also specify the cause.